# Spring xml configuration: beans:beans vs beans

Tags: spring, spring-security

What is the difference between

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">
```

and

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
```

In the former, security is configured as

```xml
<http auto-config="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/login"  access="permitAll()" />
</http>
```

whereas in the latter it would be configured as

```xml
<security:http auto-config="true">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"  access="permitAll()" />
</security:http>
```

I am not sure what the functional difference is between the two schema formats. Also can someone advise as to which is pprefereable or under which circumsances each is preferable?

Comment: See [XML namespaces](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).  In your first snippet it is most likely that *security* namespace is used as base namespace. In later *beans* namespace is used as base namespace

Comment: thanks , that's a useful pointer.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two differences

- the first is just syntactical: beans is default namespace or not (Petar Ivanov has explained this in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39614227/280244))
- the second can lead to some issues later on (when you update spring or spring-security):

**XSD with version number vs. XSD without version number**

In your first snipped you used `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd` and `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd` - here you used a fix version of the xsd's *(it is ok that spring and spring-security have different numbers)*

In your second snipped you used `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd` and `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd`. In this case spring will use the newest schemata supported by the spring and spring-security jars you use.

Answer (score 2):

The tag `beans:beans` refers to `beans` tag from `beans` namespace and the tag `beans` refer to `beans` tag from default namespace.

If the default namespace is `beans` - there is no difference at all.